# Looping list used for .append function

Tags: python, append

What I am struggling with now a bit, is getting a set of code to run, where I can automate the cycle of chosen lists, to assign different variables to different lists.

I am using .append, but what I am aiming to do is the following:

x.append(y), I'd want the x list used to be chosen from a set that I have, another list of the list names for example. I have made the following code to capture this:

```
temp_stat_list = ["10Fouls5","2Corners4","5Crosses6","80Touches92"]
stat_picker = 0
extra_stats = ["Fouls","Corners","Crosses","Touches"]
stat_list = ["foul_list","corner_list","cross_list","touch_list"]
stat_list_len = len(stat_list) - 1
while stat_picker <= stat_list_len:
    working_stat = extra_stats[stat_picker]
    working_list = stat_list[stat_picker]
    stat_len = len(working_stat)
    add_stat_home = temp_stat_list[stat_picker]
    add_stat_home = add_stat_home[:add_stat_home.find(working_stat)]
    stat_list[stat_picker].append(int(add_stat_home))
    add_stat_away = temp_stat_list[stat_picker]
    add_stat_away = add_stat_away[(add_stat_away.find(working_stat) + stat_len):]
    stat_list[stat_picker].append(int(add_stat_away))
    stat_picker = stat_picker + 1
```

Ideally in this code the part:

```
stat_list[stat_picker].append(int(add_stat_home)) 
stat_list[stat_picker].append(int(add_stat_away))
```

the stat list portion would move with the stat picker increase at the end. Effectively capturing the variables in the first run, then moving to the next, and adjusting the list accordingly. Thanks!

I've been successfully implemented this chunk with the different instances of the lists, running individually. This of course adds a fair bit of repetitive code, and I am wanting to run a simple while loop to just automate this.

I can get it to work with just manually running each list instance separately, but as a loop, I can't get it to work.

EDIT: Added temp_stat_list example content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer was a lot simpler than I thought, just needed another set of eyes. Really all we needed to do, was use a list of lists, so then the final code that worked perfectly, is the following:

```
stat_picker = 0
extra_stats = ["Fouls","Corners","Crosses","Touches"]
stat_list = [foul_list,corner_list,cross_list,touch_list]
stat_list_len = len(stat_list) - 1
while stat_picker <= stat_list_len:
    working_stat = extra_stats[stat_picker]
    working_list = stat_list[stat_picker]
    stat_len = len(working_stat)
    add_stat_home = temp_stat_list[stat_picker]
    add_stat_home = add_stat_home[:add_stat_home.find(working_stat)]
    stat_list[stat_picker].append(int(add_stat_home))
    add_stat_away = temp_stat_list[stat_picker]
    add_stat_away = add_stat_away[(add_stat_away.find(working_stat) + stat_len):]
    stat_list[stat_picker].append(int(add_stat_away))
    stat_picker = stat_picker + 1
```

The change here is that the stat_list needed to be a list of lists instead. A list of strings wouldn't be recognized as lists being applied.

Answer (score 0):

So, I deleted my other post because I realized I accidentally asked the question as an answer, instead of a comment.

Here's what I *think* you're looking for, let me know if this is it:

```
import re
temp_stat_list = ["10Fouls5","2Corners4","5Crosses6","80Touches92"]
fouls = {'home':[],
         'away':[]}
corners = {'home':[],
         'away':[]}
crosses = {'home':[],
         'away':[]}
touches = {'home':[],
         'away':[]}

for stat in temp_stat_list:
    parsed_stats = re.match(r"([0-9]+)([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", stat, re.I)
    stats = parsed_stats.groups()
    if stats[1] == "Fouls":
        fouls['home'].append(stats[0])
        fouls['away'].append(stats[2])
    elif stats[1] == "Corners":
        corners['home'].append(stats[0])
        corners['away'].append(stats[2])
    elif stats[1] == "Crosses":
        crosses['home'].append(stats[0])
        crosses['away'].append(stats[2])
    else:
        touches['home'].append(stats[0])
        touches['away'].append(stats[2])

print("Fouls: ")
print(fouls)
print("Corners: ")
print(corners)
print("Crosses: ")
print(crosses)
print("Touches: ")
print(touches)
```

This gives an output of:

```
Fouls: 
{'home': ['10'], 'away': ['5']}
Corners: 
{'home': ['2'], 'away': ['4']}
Crosses: 
{'home': ['5'], 'away': ['6']}
Touches: 
{'home': ['80'], 'away': ['92']}
```

Comment: Hey shep! So this wasn't quite what I had in mind, and it did end up introducing a lot more stuff to my code that I would break some other aspects. Turns out my list of strings was fully wrong, and aIl I needed to do was change stat_list to a list of lists. With this the lists can be cycled through properly. Far simpler than I thought, but was just my short-sightedness. Thanks anyway, you were helpful!